# Chef client for SLES 11 on PowerPC

Tags: chef-infra, sles

I'd like to install chef client in a SLES 11 with IBM Power hardware, does anybody knows if there is any way to install chef client for that distribution and hardware type ?

I've been told to use the RHEL packages but I haven't found any for PPC.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find our official platform support policy at https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc021-platform-support-policy.md. SLES on PPC is explicitly not supported at this time. The simplest option is probably to install Ruby from the SLES and then install Chef as a gem. I know there are deals in the works for zLinux and other Power stuffs, but nothing public yet.